# Prove that $A$ is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $d\times d$ matrix. Assume that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $n\geq 1$ such that $\Vert A^n\Vert\leq \varepsilon^n$. Prove that $A^d=0$.

My try: We can find a sequence $\{n_i\}$ such that $A^{n_i}\rightarrow0$. But I don't know how to prove that $A^d=0$.

Comment: Sorry; that comment was misleading. Better: let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue (complex if necessary) and $x$ an eigenvector. Use the inequality to show that $\lambda$ must be equal to $0$, so that the only eigenvalues are $0$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be a complex eigenvalue of $A$.

Then, for $X$ an eigenvector of norm $1$, $\epsilon >0$, then for such a $n$ you have 
$$|\lambda |^n=\|\lambda^n x\|=\|A^nx\|\leq \|A^n\|\leq \epsilon^n$$
so that $|\lambda|\leq\epsilon$.

So, $\lambda=0$. Now, you can change of base to make $A$ triangular in $\mathbb C$, then, its diagonal is made of $0$ so $A$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Thank you very much